# Dragging a lineString in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

How can we drag the lineString using mapbox-gl-js?
Like If we draw the lineString and if we want to drag it then how will I recalculate the all coordinates?

Comment: Maybe you could check the position of the mouse on the map while dragging in `LngLat`, and set the position of the lineString with that data.

Comment: Could you be clearer in what you are trying to achieve, with the code you have so far?